# C#: An alternative to SendKeys outside of a form?

Tags: c#, sendmessage, sendkeys, postmessage

I am trying to send a string to a textbox control in an external application by using the keybd events api, however I don't particularly want to send each character to a string using this method and would know SendKeys would be appropriate.

I have gained focus in the text box by sending a Ctrl+L command via keybd events (an application shortcut).

However, i'm executing this code from within a class and therefore the windows.forms namespace is not applicable and I cannot access SendKeys...

Are there any alternatives? (Do PostMessage and SendMessage have any application here?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any reason why you couldn't use SendKeys from a class.  Just be sure to put the `using System.Windows.Forms` directive at the top of the file.  Add the reference if this class lives in its own class library project.